# Child of Constraint creates strange glitch?

Tags: animation, transforms, constraints

When I parent the weapon magazine with the hands, they follow , but the magazine rotates! The magazine also goes out of its desired position. How do I fix this?

No child.

[image: With no child]

With Child Added.

[image: With child added]

Comment: FIXED ! I had to use Copy transform

Comment: Feel free to add that as a proper answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

In "Child of" panel select the "set inverse" button. Most of the time, this resolves this sort of thing for me. I can't explain the mechanics of it. If this does't work and you want to go back to the original, click on the "clear inverse."

Comment: with I could upvote this so many times! Thank you! Saved my project

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use the copy transform constraint, as it connects it in a way that it follows the magazine.

Comment: It would be nice if you could also add some more detail on how to use the constraint and why it works where the child of did not, to better help other users with the same issue.

Comment: hm , im still having the same issue with copy transform , except it follows the mag ... gandalf would you have any clue on how to keep the hands from chaning its position when the constraint is applied?