# Child of constraint. Bow Suddenly rotates

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm making an archer and connecting my left hand to the bow but every time I move the hand the bow suddenly rotates. I don't know if its the main bone which I've used for the Constraint

[Child of Constraint creates strange glitch?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/child-of-constraint-creates-)
I've tried this guide transform and the inverse but still same result.
[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2953" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2953/)

This is my archer Sorry my first time to use the blend exchange

Comment: Maybe "copy transforms" instead of "child of"?

Comment: The copy transforms seems to work fine. Is there a way so I could point my bow toward? bro. or should I ask another question? @lemon

Comment: Adjust the base bow bone in the wanted direction. The idea is to make it always aligned with its constraint. So you may adjust its children bones around it

Comment: @lemon Thanks bro for answering my questions that solved my problem.